# RangeError (index): Invalid Value: Only valid value is 0: 1 error in MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, range

i'm pretty new to programming and currently facing an issue where one of my screens wont display. The screen is sort of like a shopping cart screen where it displays the items the user has chosen. I'm very lost because for some reason flutter tells me the error is located in MaterialApp in main.

Here is my main.dart

```
import 'package:eat_easy_project/assistantMethod/shopping_List_Counter.dart';
import 'package:eat_easy_project/global/global.dart';
import 'package:eat_easy_project/splashScreen/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

Future<void> main() async
 {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

 
  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (c)=> ShoppingListCounter()),
      ],
      child:  MaterialApp(
        title: 'EatEasy Project',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
         
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const MySplashScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
  
}
```

and below is the cart screen where it the other code where it shoul've displayed

```
import 'package:eat_easy_project/models/ingredients.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShoppingListDesign extends StatefulWidget 
{
  final Ingredients? model;
  BuildContext? context;
  final List <int>? separateIngredientQuantitiesList;

  ShoppingListDesign({
    this.model,
    this.context,
    this.separateIngredientQuantitiesList,
  });

  @override
  State<ShoppingListDesign> createState() => _ShoppingListDesignState();
}

class _ShoppingListDesignState extends State<ShoppingListDesign> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.cyan,
      child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 165,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Image.network(widget.model!.ingredientAvatarUrl!, width: 140, height: 120,),
                const SizedBox(width: 6,), 
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      widget.model!.ingredientName!,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontFamily: "Kiwi",
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 1.0,
                    ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                          "x ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontFamily: "Acme",
                          ),
                    ),
                          Text(
                          widget.separateIngredientQuantitiesList.toString(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontFamily: "Acme",
                          ),
                    ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "Price: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            "RM ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            widget.model!.ingredientPrice.toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm following a guide from udemy to help me code and for some reason even though I copied the exact same code with minor adjustments, I still got this error. My database json is located in firebase.

Error in detail:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76wwd.png)

Error for assitantMethod led me to var quanNumber = int.parse(listIngredientCharacters[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76wwd.png).toString());

```
 separateIngredientUIDs()
 {
 List<String> separateIngredientUIDsList=[], defaultIngredientList= 
 [];
 int i=0;

 defaultIngredientList = 
  sharedPreferences!.getStringList("userShoppingList")!;

 for(i; i<defaultIngredientList.length; i++)
{
  String ingredient = defaultIngredientList[i].toString(); 
  var pos = ingredient.lastIndexOf(":");
  String getIngredientID = (pos != -1) ? ingredient.substring(0, pos) 
   : ingredient;

    print("\nThis is ingredientID now = " + getIngredientID);

   separateIngredientUIDsList.add(getIngredientID);
    }

  print("\nThis is Ingredients List now = " );
  print(separateIngredientUIDsList);

  return separateIngredientUIDsList;
  }

 addIngredientToCart(String? ingredientUID, BuildContext context, int 
 ingredientCounter)
  {
  List<String>? tempList = 
    sharedPreferences!.getStringList("userShoppingList");
  tempList!.add(ingredientUID! + ":$ingredientCounter");

   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user")
  .doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).update({
    "userShoppingList": tempList,
    }).then((value)
   {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Ingredient Added Successfully.");

    sharedPreferences!.setStringList("userShoppingList", tempList);
    
    //update badge
    Provider.of<ShoppingListCounter>(context, listen: 
  false).displayShoppingListIngredientNumber();
  });
}

 separateIngredientQuantities()
  {
 List<int> separateIngredientQuantityList=[]; 
 List<String> defaultIngredientList=[];
 int i=0;

defaultIngredientList = 
   sharedPreferences!.getStringList("userShoppingList")!;

for(i; i<defaultIngredientList.length; i++)
{
  String ingredient = defaultIngredientList[i].toString(); 
  
  List<String> listIngredientCharacters = 
  ingredient.split(":").toList();

  var quanNumber = int.parse(listIngredientCharacters[0].toString());

  print("\nThis is Quantity Number = " + quanNumber.toString());

  separateIngredientQuantityList.add(quanNumber);
}

  print("\nThis is Quantity List now = " );
  print(separateIngredientQuantityList);

    return separateIngredientQuantityList;
 }
```

Error for shoppinglistscreen led me to separateIngredientQuantities();

```
class ShoppingListScreen extends StatefulWidget {

Ingredients? model;
 ShoppingListScreen({this.model});

@override
 State<ShoppingListScreen> createState() => _ShoppingListScreenState();
 }

class _ShoppingListScreenState extends State<ShoppingListScreen> 
 {

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

  separateIngredientQuantities();
 }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar
    (
     flexibleSpace: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Color.fromARGB(255, 192, 234, 240),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 108, 173, 70),
            ],
            begin:  FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end:  FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
          )
        ),
      ),
    title: const Text(
      "EatEasy",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: 
   FontWeight.bold,)
    ),
        centerTitle: true,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
    actions: [
      Stack(
        children: [
          IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Colors.cyan,),
          onPressed: ()
        {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> 
      ShoppingListScreen(model: widget.model,)));
        },
      ),
      
      Positioned(
        child: Stack(
          children:  [
            const Icon(
              Icons.brightness_1,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 29, 88, 31),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 3,
              right: 4,
              child: Center(
                child: Consumer<ShoppingListCounter>(
                  builder: (context, counter, c)
                  {
                    return Text(
                      counter.count.toString(), 
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 209, 218, 226)),
                    );
                  }
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      ],  
      ),
    ],
    ),
    floatingActionButton: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        SizedBox(width: 10,),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            label: const Text("Clear List", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.clear_all),
            onPressed: ()
            {

            },

            
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            label: const Text("Calculate Total", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.calculate),
            onPressed: ()
            {

            },

            
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [

        //overall total amount
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: true,
          delegate: TextWidgetHeader(title: "Total Amount = 120"),

        ),
        
        //display cart ingredients with quantity
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("ingredients")
          .where("ingredientUID", whereIn: separateIngredientUIDs())
          .orderBy("ingredientPrice", descending: true)
          .snapshots(),

          builder: (context, snapshot)
          {   
            return !snapshot.hasData 
            ? SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Center(child: 
        circularProgress()),) 
            : snapshot.data!.docs.length == 0 
            ? //startBuildingList
            Container()
            : SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index)
              {
                Ingredients model = Ingredients.fromJson(
                  snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()! as Map<String, 
     dynamic>,
                );

                return ShoppingListDesign(
                model: model,
                context: context,
                separateIngredientQuantitiesList: [index] ,
                );
              },
              //childCount: snapshot.hasData ? 
       snapshot.data!.docs.length : 0,
              ),
            );

          },
        ),
      ],
    ),

 );
 }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code gives you the message error ?

Comment: which line is causing this error?

Comment: oh one sec i forgot to mention that

Comment: added the error message from debug console

Comment: The error comes from the shopping_list_screen, click in the link and then, what does it show you ? (also the assistant_Method)

Comment: oh okay ill update where it brings me to

Comment: edited, sorry still very new to stackoverflow

Comment: you didn't include assistant_Method code in the question

Comment: okay, ill include the whole code

Comment: whole code included for both assistant_,method and shopping_list_screen

Comment: after further checking, it seems that var quanNumber = int.parse(listIngredientCharacters[1].toString());   in assistand_method is the problem, but i can't find a fitting solution..